# android append '...' at the end textview

Tags: android, append, textview

I have a View to that I need to add some text.
The used View is:

```
<TextView 
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:layout_gravity="center" 
  android:maxLines="3"
  android:layout_height="70dp" 
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:textSize="12dp" />
```

The problem i have is, if this text contains more than 3 line it just shows three line but no indication  that it cut some line.
I want to append '...' at end of third line if it cut some data.

Comment: You got 3 correct answers, you should really mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
<TextView android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:gravity="center_vertical" 
   android:layout_gravity="center" 
   android:maxLines="3" 
   android:layout_height="70dp" 
   android:textColor="#000000" 
   android:textSize="12dp" 
   android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

Use this code and it will work fine, the code `android:ellipsize="end"` will change this for you.

Comment: This won't work. The documentation states: If set, causes words that are longer than the view is wide to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle. In my test this causes a four line text view to stop displaying Text after the second line because at the end of the second line a word should be broken in the middle. Ellipsize won't put dots on the end of the textview after the third line.

Comment: This will work with      android:singleLine="true" , not with android:maxLines

Comment: Worked for me. no issues.

Answer (score 4):

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: add android:scrollHorizontally="true"

Answer (score 1):

It's not working if only we add `android:ellipsize="end"`, we also need to add `android:maxLines="3"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:layout_gravity="center" 
 android:maxLines="3"
 android:layout_height="70dp" 
 android:textColor="#000000"
 android:textSize="12dp" 
 android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

add android:ellipsize="end"

Comment: Thanks for that answer but still i have some problem and i posted on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021293/android-append-at-the-end-textview-edit